# What happened with registered devices those turned off their notification in iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I googled but not able find my desired solution. My Questions are following related to push notification.

- What if registered device turned off its push notification and server broadcast notification. Is notification place in waiting list (e.g when device turned on notification it gets notification) ? or Reject ? or Server keep sending ?
- If server keep sending how to tackle this situation, I mean is there any way that we can find our some client turned off notification then we'll not send notification to APNS?

If someone already asked then kindly reference those question instead of down vote.

Looking for answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

APNS docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Your server - what Apple calls the provider - maintains a list of device tokens that have registered for your notifications.

When a device turns off push notifications, you should remove its device token from your list.

So far as I know, if you attempt to push to a device that has turned off push notifications, your provider will receive an error, and the push notification will not be queued. It should be easy enough to test using a device.